# Why is Bluetooth address now showing up as AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, node.js, pi-zero-w

The issue I'm having is with my Raspberry Pi 3. I'm running this CLI-only with the **Raspbian Jessie Lite** build.

At some point in using this device, my Bluetooth address changed to `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA`. I believe this is preventing me from pairing Bluetooth devices. I was able to pair it in the past, but now it does not see anything when scanning.

I'm trying to add a Flic button to this Raspberry Pi 3, but for some reason, when I'm running the scanner utility and then press the Flic, it's not pairing. I was able to pair another Flic button with this Raspberry Pi 3 just earlier this week. Sadly, I already unpaired it so I cannot test if it still works.

```
pi@Raspberry-Pi-3:~ $ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING
        RX bytes:1816 acl:0 sco:0 events:100 errors:0
        TX bytes:5009 acl:0 sco:0 commands:99 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'Raspberry-Pi-3'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous,
        HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x0
        LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x2209
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

Strangely, I have two Raspberry Pi Zero W devices and both of those pair just fine with the same Flic buttons.

Another thing is the `bluetoothd` version is a lot higher on the Raspberry Pi 3 compared to the Raspberry Pi Zero W devices.

```
pi@Raspberry-Pi-3:~ $ bluetoothd -v
5.43
```

versus

```
pi@Raspberry-Pi-Zero-W:~ $ bluetoothd -v
5.23
```

What can I do to fix this on the Raspberry Pi 3? I assume it all traces back to the Bluetooth address being `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is Bluez version 5.43 on this version of Raspbian.

You need to downgrade to 5.23, the standard version for the Jessie build, to be able to use Bluetooth properly. This is probably caused by an apt source.

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to see if any of the files in there are pointing to test releases.