# Bluetooth MAC Address Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect two raspberry pi 3 betweem them via bluetooth.

But the fact is that their MAC addresses are AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA

Does anyone knows how to **assign them a real mac address** in order to be able to transfer data via bluetooth betweem them?

This is what hciconfig tells:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
    BD Address: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:801 acl:0 sco:0 events:53 errors:0
    TX bytes:2526 acl:0 sco:0 commands:53 errors:0
```

Comment: The [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69222/why-is-bluetooth-address-now-showing-up-as-aaaaaaaaaaaa/69290) here may help you solve the problem

Comment: Thanks u! I'm going to take a look it seems to be the same problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Bluetooth address now showing up as AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69222/why-is-bluetooth-address-now-showing-up-as-aaaaaaaaaaaa)