# How to send data between raspberrys via bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth

I just want to send data between my both raspberrys pi 3 via bluetooth ble.

does anyone know how to do exactly?
I'm able to see each other, pair and connect them. But I can not send data between them.

I've got installed bluez and also here are the versions installed

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothd --version
5.23
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl --version
5.30
```

I think that maybe the problem could be with the address they have, as following shown:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
    BD Address: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:801 acl:0 sco:0 events:53 errors:0
    TX bytes:2526 acl:0 sco:0 commands:53 errors:0
```

So, **what can I do to send data betweem them via Bluetooth ble?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `bluetooth-sendto --device=12:34:56:78:9A:BC filename`

Get the device address using hcitool. This command will popup a dialog showing file transfer progress. This will not work on headless.

Or try using `obexftp -b <BTAddr> -v -p <FileToPut>`

Comment: I'll try it but the problem that I think I have is that both RPIs have the same addres AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA when I do the hciconfig

Comment: Each bluetooth device has its own unique identifier from the mfg. You may  have a problem with the bluez. Refer to [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69222/why-is-bluetooth-address-now-showing-up-as-aaaaaaaaaaaa/69290) to resolve that first.